# Xcode 7 UI test loop through all switches

Tags: xcode, swift, ios9, ui-testing

Is there a possibility to test all the switches that are present in the app.tables.switches dictionary. When I record the test the line get added with a string as key like:

```
app.tables.switches["Kantoor, kntr"].tap()
```

But I'd like to loop trough all the switches with a for-loop like (code doesn't work):

```
for index in 0...app.tables.switches.count {
    XCTAssertTrue(app.tables.switches[index].value, "")
}
```

This is a check to verify if all the switches of every row is enabled/disabled after I clicked the "disable all"-button.

Comment: ``for `switch` in app.tables.switches { XCTAssertTrue(`switch`.value, "") }``

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I finally found the solution, it's way simpler than I expected but used the wrong approach. This fix is to use te following command:

```
let firstSwitch = app.tables.switches.elementBoundByIndex(0)
```

Comment: This is not what you asked in the question.

Comment: "loop trough all the switches with a for-loop" this is what I asked.

Comment: You need to change the title as well as the main request appears in the question to reflect what do you really want.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get to the values in a dictionary, you just use the `values` property:

```
let dict = [1: true, 2: false, 3: true]

dict.values // [false, true, true]
```

If you want to check that even value in a dictionary is `true` with a for loop, you can do this:

```
for val in dict.values {
  XCTAssertTrue(val)
}
```

To be a little more informative, you can loop through the keys and values at the same time, and use the keys as an error message in case you get a `false`:

```
let dict = ["a": true, "b": false, "c": true]

for (key,val) in dict {
  XCTAssertTrue(val, key)
}
```

Or, using the `contains` method, you can do this nice one-liner:

```
XCTAssertFalse(dict.values.contains(!))
```

Which basically tests that the dictionary does *not* contain a value which is *not* `true`.

Comment: yes that's exactly what I would do when I'm implementing a unit test. But in this case I only want to test the UI part of the interface.

Comment: Is your `switches` dictionary a dictionary of strings and bools? i.e, is its type `[String:Bool]`?

Comment: As you can see I can call the switches by using their description but I'd rather describe the dictionary as [String:AnyObject] because when I try to print the app.tables.switches as an variable my debugger tells me that the type is XCUIElementQuery.